# DropDownList tag helper while using ViewBag it is not return the selected item Id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3

Controller ViewBag is following:

`ViewBag.Products = new SelectList(await _productService.GetAllProduct(), "ProductId", "ProductName");`

Razor page DropDownList tag helper is following:

`@Html.DropDownList("ProductId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Products, "Select Product", new { @class ="form-control" })`

When I selected the value of the dropdown and submit the product is cannot return to controller, its return null Value

Expecting productId return to the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess there is some issue at the controller's parameter. The model binding will check the client post value and auto map the productID.

The dropdownlist codes is looks good.

I have also write a test demo like this:

```
<form asp-action="ProductUpdate">
    @Html.DropDownList("ProductId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Products, "Select Product", new { @class ="form-control" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

For example, if your product ID is int value, then you should set the action like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ProductUpdate(int ProductId)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View( );
    }
```

Result:

[image]